# как из метода subscribe вернуть observable значение в rxjava2?

Tags: java, kotlin, rxjava2, room

Идея такова:
Вставляю список в БД, подписываюсь на вставку, при успешной вставке, возвращается список id вставленных элементов, по этому списку id прохожусь в цикле и получаю строки по id, записываю строки в массив. После этот массив хочу вывести в консоль.

Описание кода:
При вызове метода insert из метода insertDatums(), хочу получить наблюдаемый список insertedDatas, т.к если просто получать список insertedDatas, он почему то пустой. Список insertedDatas не заполняется данными при запуске программы, но при отладке заполняется.. 
Как из метода subscribe вернуть заполненный список insertedDatas с типом Observable? Или есть другие решения?

```
    class InspectionsImpl(fragment: Fragment, contextForInspections: Context) : Inspections {

        var datum: Datum? = null

        val repository: AlfaKndRepository = ViewModelProviders.of(fragment).get(AlfaKndViewModel::class.java).repository

        var insertedDatas:  MutableList<Datum>? = null

    override fun insertDatums(): Observable<MutableList<Datum>> {
    //хочу, что бы метод insert вернул заполенный insertedDatas с типом Observable     
return insert(dataForInsert!!)
        }

     private fun insert(datasForInsert: List <Datum>): Observable <MutableList<Datum>> { 
         //вставляю список в БД
         Observable.fromCallable { repository.insertList(datasForInsert) } 
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())  
            .flatMapIterable { it.map { it.toInt() } }.toList() 
            //получаю список id вставленных строк
            .subscribe({ 
                for (it in it.iterator()){
                     //получаю из БД элементы по id
                     repository.getById(it)
                        //хочу записать строки полученные по id в массив insertedDatas, при отладке все записывается, а если запустить код, то массив пуст, поэтому хочу вернуть insertedDatas, как Observable
                        .subscribe({insertedDatas!!.add(it)}, {Log.d(TAG, it.message)})
}
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код. И куда вам и что надо вернуть?

Comment: может вы читаете данные до того, как они пришли?

Comment: @Komdosh так то оно и есть конечно, тут потоковая работа, при отладке все нормально записывается, а когда прогу запускаю, то по нулям

Comment: Вы имеете в виду что-то такое? Вернуть из `insert()` `Observable.fromCallable { repository.insertList(datasForInsert) }.map {it.map{it.toInt()}}.map{ if(insertedDatas==null) insertedDatas = it.toMutableList() else { insertedDatas.addAll(it) } return insertedDatas }` ? Т.е. суть в том, что подписываться вам надо, кажется, не в методе InspectionsImpl класса, а там, где вы его вызываете. Ну и в целом что-то странное и излишнее вы, кажется, делаете

Comment: @ЮрийСПб мне тоже кажется, что я делаю излишние вещи, но как еще получить строки, которые я вставил в БД?

Comment: Про лишнее я скорее про множество `subscribe`. Обычно делают цепочку вызовов операторов и `subscribe` только один.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, так и сделал, мыслил по другому, хотел через цикл, когда проще было через map:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ЮрийСПб спасибо, так и сделал, мыслил по другому, хотел через цикл, когда проще было через map:

```
private fun insert(datasForInsert: List<Datum>): Single<MutableList<Datum>> {
   return Observable.fromCallable { repository.insertList(datasForInsert) }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           //перебираем список
           .flatMapIterable {
                //элемент списка приобразовываем в Long
                it.map {
                    it.toInt()
                }
            }
            //объеденить выпущенные элементы из map в список
            .toList()
           .map {
               it.toMutableList()
           }
           .map {
               it.map {it ->
                   repository.getById(it)
               }
           }.map {
               it.toMutableList()
           }.flatMap {
               Single.just(it)
           }
}
```